# Including a date in a filename

Tags: files, solaris, rename

Inside a directory, there are 150 files named like `ABLIMITS.TXT`. How do I rename them to `ABLIMITS_date.txt` prompting the user for date?

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a little unclear (how can 150 files in a single parent dir all have the same filename?), so here is an example of doing it with a single file named `ABLIMITS.TXT`, which you can extrapolate as necessary:

In a POSIX shell:

#### Using the current date

```
mv ABLIMITS.TXT "ABLIMITS_$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').TXT"
```

#### Prompting the user for a date

```
read -rp "Please enter date: " date
mv ABLIMITS.TXT "ABLIMITS_${date}.TXT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you want to take the user input, and make sure it follows a standard format (e.g. YYYY-MM-DD). So let's try something like this:

```
for i in *
do
  read -p "Enter date for $i: " d
  mv "$i" "${i%.*}_$(date +%Y-%m-%d -d "$d").${i##*.}"
done
```

You can read the man page for date to get more information on the format.